# How to calculate this radix sorting algorithm complexity?

Tags: algorithm, radix

I have this following code. I need to calculate this algorithm complexity but i have no idea where to start. This algorithm has 3 nested loops so i guess its complexity is n^3 or am i wrong?

public static void RadixSort(DataArray data)
        {
            IList> digits = new List>();

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            digits.Add(new List<int>());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
            {
                int digit = (int)((data[j] % Math.Pow(10, i + 1)) / Math.Pow(10, i));

                digits[digit].Add((int)data[j]);
            }

            int index = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < digits.Count; k++)
            {
                IList<int> selDigit = digits[k];

                for (int l = 0; l < selDigit.Count; l++)
                {
                    data.Swap(index++, selDigit[l]);
                    //data[index++] = selDigit[l];
                }
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < digits.Count; k++)
            {
                digits[k].Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `data.Lenght` exactly? Either the `i` or the `j`-loop is wrong. The `i`-loop should run over the length of the key in digits.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating complexity is more complex than just look at the number of nested loops. If you have a triple nested loop like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
```

it will be O(n³), *assuming n is not changing in the loop*. However, if you consider your case:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        for(int k=0; k<m; k++)
```

the time complexity will instead be O(m²n).

And even the simplest sorting algorithms, like bouble sort, selection sort and insertions sort is O(n²), so if your implementation is worse than that you're doing something wrong. The time complexity for radix sort is O(wn), where w is a measure of the size of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

When uncertain about complexity, a reasonable approach is to add counters to the inner-loop code and at the end of the routine print out the counts.  Next, vary the size of the input to see how the results change.  The empirical results can immediately confirm or deny your analytic or intuited results.